# rxjs repeat and async pipe added and removed to the dome cause value to be null

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

i have a class which is responsible for timer. that contains observable like that

```js
    merge(
      this._start$,
      this._pause$
    )
      .pipe(
        switchMap(val => (val ? interval(1000) : EMPTY)),
        map(()=>-1),
        scan((acc: number, curr: number) => acc + curr, time),
        takeWhile(val => val >= 0),
        startWith(time),
        takeUntil(this._stop$),
        repeat(),
        tap(val=>{
          if(val===0){
            this._finished$.next();
          }
        }),
        takeUntil(this._destroy$)
      );
```

and come helpers methods.
When i'm projecting it directly in to template like {{Timer.watch$|async}} there is no problem whatsoever. But when i'm adding the same snippets inside *ngIf it default's to starting value

```html
<span *ngIf="condition">
            {{Timer.watch$|async}}
            </span>
```

Comment: What's the condition? How this._start$ and this._pause$ get their values to emit?

Comment: You haven't posted enough code for someone to reproduce or debug your problem, but you likely have the starting value you're looking for coming after the `ngIf` has been evaluated.  `| async` will start a subscription some time after the component is added, so you likely need to put the `next` value into `_start` after that happens.  You could also consider using `[hidden]` instead of `ngIf` if you want that subscription regardless of rendering condition.

Comment: @possum it is strait forward and no additional logic attached to it, but be my guest https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-d5d3qm?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score -2):

What happens is that in switchTimer() method, when you start a timer (this.currentTimer.start()), the conditional block with timer hasn't rendered yet. It is because angular change detection runs after click() callback is finished.

You can fix it by changing _start into replaySubject:

```
  private readonly _start$: ReplaySubject<true> = new ReplaySubject();
```

This way it will emit last value when subscribed to. And that's it, both timers count down now.

There's also another solution, but it's a dirty fix. In switchTimer() method you can replace

```
this.currentTimer.start()
```

with

```
setTimeout(() => this.currentTimer.start(), 0);
```

This way timer will be started after angular is done with rendering html. But it's more of a fun fact here, normally I'd go with the first fix.

Comment: no first solution will restart timer from starting point and not from the point it was paused.